# Detect when Element attached to DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to check whether element attached to the  DOM in javascript because I want  to do some action when element gets attached to the DOM(**on element attach event I want to do some action**). Is there anything like addAttachHandler like GWT which is also present in javascript?

Comment: Your title might be better as "*Detect when element attached to DOM*". ;-)

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver ..?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which tells you when elements are added or removed from the DOM tree. It is fully supported by all modern browsers (IE11+).

The Elemento library (Apache 2.0 license) has [a GWT JsInterop implementation of an attach/detach listener](https://github.com/hal/elemento/blob/develop/core/src/main/java/org/jboss/gwt/elemento/core/BodyObserver.java) that uses `MutationObserver` behind the scenes. You might be able to draw inspiration from that code, or use it directly.

Comment: Please add a code example rather than referring to links.

Comment: @Kyle Baker, I would normally show code, but the question doesn't actually ask for a code sample, and it'd take some time to put together a good example, so I tried to hint at the direction and leave it as "an exercise for the reader". It would be great if you can add an answer with code examples though.